# Search items in wxPython ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, taskmanager, listctrl

In simple terms , I am building a toy task manager with wxpython and psutil. I have a searchCtrl on top of the list. But I couldn't find a way to show only the matched items in that the list. I tried creating a list of all tasks and then deleting all items but the matched items , but unfortunately that doesn't work as the list was getting updated every 5 seconds.

```py
    def on_search_task(self , e): # this function got executed when the a search event is fired
        index = 0
        keepitems = []
        for x in self.alltasks:
            for a in dict(x).values():
                if a.find(e.GetString()) >= 0:
                    print("match at {} - {}".format(index , self.alltasks.index(x)))
                    print(self.alltasks.index(x) == index)
                else:
                    keepitems.append(index)

            index += 1

        for x in keepitems:
            self.task_list.DeleteItem(x)
```

I hope I was able to describe the problem and my goal. Source code with current progress is also available on GitHub here https://github.com/bauripalash/taskboy for further reference.

Comment: why are you updating the list every 5 sec.? Is iot required to update it? Are you using timer? Maybe when you filter the list you should stop it?

Comment: every 5 second, the data of tasks such as RAM usage, CPU usage are being updated. I could just stop the timer and filter items but the filtered item's data will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a "virtual" list control, i.e. one returning items on demand, and do the filtering in your `OnGetItemText()`. See [the wiki](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ListCtrl.html) for a brief explanation of virtual list controls.